# How to solve $\int xe^x \cos(2x) \mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int xe^x \cos(2x) \mathrm dx$$

I have been trying to solve this for some time by using integration by parts, but can't figure out how to divide it into suitable parts. It becomes some sort of loop. Can anyone help as to which ones I should take as $u$ and $v$?
Also, is there any other method to approach this problem? Because, integration by parts might get lengthy, perhaps.

Comment: If the integral is $I$, then try getting an equation from the integration by parts to solve for $I$

Comment: For $u$ take $x$, and for $\mathrm dv$ take $e^x \cos(2x) \mathrm dx$. Good luck!

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak I am trying that now, do I have to apply integration by parts twice, then? Because the second term in the expression causes problem

Comment: @Anne: to find $v$ you will have to integrate by parts too. In that integral I will suggest 'new' $u= \cos(2x)$, and 'new' $\mathrm dv = e^x \mathrm dx$. Upon applying 'new' integration by parts you will have to apply this method once again.  So, in total $3$ times.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint.** A small trick: note that $\cos(2x)=\operatorname{Re} (e^{2ix})$, so we consider the integral
$$I=\int xe^xe^{2ix}\mathrm dx=\int xe^{(1+2i)x}\mathrm dx.$$
A trivial integration by parts will give the expression of $I$ and the desired integral is obtained by taking the real part of $I$.

The expression for $I$:

> \begin{align*} I=\int xe^{(1+2i)x}\mathrm dx=\frac{xe^{(1+2i)x}}{1+2i}-\frac{e^{(1+2i)x}}{(1+2i)^2}+C.\end{align*}

Taking the real part:

> We compute that \begin{align*} \frac{x}{1+2i}-\frac{1}{(1+2i)^2}=\frac{(-3-4i)(x-1+2xi)}{25}=\frac{5x+3-2(5x-2)i}{25}, \end{align*} hence $$I= \frac{5x+3-2(5x-2)i}{25}e^x(\cos 2x+i\sin 2x)+C$$ and thus $$\operatorname{Re} I=\frac{e^x}{25}\left(2(5x-2)\sin 2x+(5x+3)\cos 2x\right)+C.$$

Comment: I never thought complex numbers might get used here! I have used it, and been able to arrive at the answer. Thank you very much, this is a very effective approach!

Comment: @Anne You're welcome. Glad to help you. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also make a guess of the solution.

Because of the terms which are present in the integrand, *assume* that
$$\int x\,e^x \cos(2x) \, dx=e^x\Big( (a+b x) \cos(2x)+(c +d x)\sin(2x) \Big)$$

Differentiate both sides and use Taylor series around $x=0$ (do not include the $e^x$ terms). This would give
$$(a+b+2 c)+x (-4 a+b+2 c+4 d-1)-2 x^2 (a+3 b+2 c-d)+$$ $$\frac{2}{3}
   x^3 (4 a-3 b-2 c-8 d+3)+\frac{2}{3} x^4 (a+5 b+2 c-2
   d)+O\left(x^5\right)$$

So
$$a+b+2c=0$$
$$-4 a+b+2 c+4 d-1=0$$
$$a+3 b+2 c-d=0$$
$$4 a-3 b-2 c-8 d+3=0$$

Solving
$$a=\frac 3{25} \qquad b=\frac 15 \qquad c=-\frac 4 {25}\qquad d=\frac 25$$

Checking the next coefficient
$$a+5 b+2 c-2  d=0$$

Try the same with
$$\int x^2\,e^x \cos(2x) \, dx$$ using quadratic polynomials.

Comment: Thanks very much! That assumption in the first bit really simplifies things a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Integrating by parts twice yields $$
\int e^{a x} \cos (b x) dx= \frac{e^{a x}}{a^2+b^2} [a \cos (b x)+b \sin (b x)]+C
$$
Differentiating both sides w.r.t. $a$ gives

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int x e^{a x} \cos (b x) d x = & \frac{e^{a x}}{\left(a^2+b^2\right)^2}\left[b\left(a^2 x-2 a+b^2 x\right) \sin (b x)+\left(a^3 x-a^2+a b^2 x+b^2\right) \cos (b x)\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
Putting $a=1$ and $b=2$ yields our integral

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int x e^x \cos (2 x) d x = & \frac{1}{25} e^x\left[\begin{array}{l}
2(x-2+4 x) \sin (2 x)+(x-1+4 x+4) \cos (2 x)]
\end{array}\right. \\
= & \frac{1}{25} e^x[2(5 x-2) \sin (2 x)+(5 x+3) \cos (2 x)
\end{aligned}
$$
In general, differentiating further w.r.t. $a$ by $n$ times yields $$
\boxed{\int x^n e^{a x} \cos (b x) d x=\frac{d^n}{d a^n}\left[\frac{e^{a x}}{a^2+b^2}(a \cos (b x)+b \sin (b x))\right]}
$$

Comment: Thank you, the general expression is very helpful too

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach:

Let find first $\displaystyle{I_1 =\int e^x \cos(2x) \mathrm dx}$.
We can integrate by parts:

\begin{aligned}
I_1 & = \int e^x \cos(2x) \mathrm dx = \cases{u = \cos(2x) \implies du = -2\sin(2x) \mathrm dx\\ \mathrm dv = e^x \mathrm dx \implies v = e^x} =
& \\
& = e^x\cos(2x)+2\int e^x\sin(2x) \mathrm dx=\\
& \\
& = \cases{u=\sin(2x) \implies \mathrm du = 2\cos(2x) \mathrm dx\\\mathrm dv=e^x \mathrm dx \implies v = e^x}=e^x\cos(2x)+2e^x\sin(2x)-4\int e^x \cos(2x) \mathrm dx = \\
& \\
& = e^x(\cos(2x) + 2\sin(2x)) - 4I_1 
\end{aligned}

Hence, we have:
$$5I_1 = e^x(\cos(2x) + 2\sin(2x)) \iff I_1=\boxed{\frac{1}{5}e^x(\cos(2x) + 2\sin(2x))}.$$

With similar approach we will find:

$\displaystyle{I_2 = \int e^x \sin(2x) \mathrm dx = \boxed{\frac{1}{5}e^x(\sin(2x) - 2\cos(2x))}.}$

Now, to find $\displaystyle{I=\int x e^x \cos(2x) \mathrm dx}$ we will integrate by parts too:

\begin{aligned}
I&=\int x e^x \cos(2x) \mathrm dx = \cases{u = x \implies \mathrm du = \mathrm dx\\ \mathrm dv = e^x \cos(2x) \mathrm dx \implies v=\int e^x \cos(2x) \mathrm dx = I_1} =\\
& \\
& = \frac{1}{5}xe^x(\cos(2x) + 2\sin(2x))-\int\frac{1}{5}e^x(\cos(2x) + 2\sin(2x))\mathrm dx =
& \\
& = \frac{1}{5}xe^x(\cos(2x) + 2\sin(2x))-\frac{1}{5}I_1-\frac{2}{5}I_2=
& \\
& =\boxed{\frac{1}{5}xe^x(\cos(2x) + 2\sin(2x))-\frac{1}{25}e^x(\cos(2x) + 2\sin(2x)) - \frac{2}{25}e^x(\sin(2x) - 2\cos(2x)) + c.}
\end{aligned}

Comment: Thank you very much